# How to use phpmailer 5.5 on PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am about to upgrade from Ubunut 16.04 to 20.04 including PHP from 7.0 to 7.4. All my applications throw the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\Exception' not found in /home/www/project/app_global/class.phpmailer.php:1721
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/project/app_global/class.phpmailer.php(1519): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->mailSend()
#1 /home/www/project/app_global/class.phpmailer.php(1353): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->postSend()
#2 /home/www/project/app_global/app_database.inc(92): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->send()
#3 /home/www/project/app_global/app_database.inc(110): check_db_down()
#4 /home/www/project/app_global/app_database.inc(468): db_connect()
#5 /home/www/project/subapp_cities/index.php(10): include('/home/www/findi...')
#6 {main}
  thrown in /home/www/project/app_global/class.phpmailer.php on line 1721
```

I am using phpmailer 5.5 and do not want to upgrade the existing applications at this moment. Is there a way to get them running again with the existing phpmailer integration?

Part of the code:

```
require_once INSTALL_DIR_GLOBAL.'app_global/class.phpmailer.php'; 
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Comment: Does your autoloader still work?

Comment: good question. How do I check this? I can't really rember how I got this running several years back.

Comment: You should show some of your code, like where the application starts. If it is using composer to autoload that might be a point to look at.

Comment: I updated my question illustrating that loading of a file "class.phpmailer.php' which is loaded in several of my files.

Answer (score 1):

You have PHPMailer 6-style calling code trying to use a PHPMailer 5 library. PHPMailer 5 does't use a namespace, so your FQCN doesn't point at anything, hence the error. Do this instead:

```
require_once INSTALL_DIR_GLOBAL.'app_global/class.phpmailer.php'; 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

If the script you're calling it *from* has its own namespace, then you would need to alias it in there:

```
namespace foo;
use PHPMailer;
```